# Segmentation fault for Using Array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

If I write as following, Segmentation fault occurs. But if I write `printf(messages[0])` or `printf(messages[1])`, I don't have error. WHY? I wanted to print all members of array using "for".

```
void givetag(char *array[]); //define function

int main() 
{
    char* messages[3];
    givetag(messages); //sub function 
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++) 
    { 
        printf(messages[i]);
    }
}

void givetag(char *array[])  
{ 
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) 
    {
        array[i]= (char*) malloc(10);
        scanf("%s", array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling as C, or C++?  Please don't tag both.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a956a1207bc2bc3

Comment: Show us your inputs.

Comment: `malloc(10)` seems awfully small.

Comment: Segmentation fault occurs ... when you do *what*?!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void 
givetag(char *array[])  
{ 
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        array[i]= (char*) malloc(100);
        scanf("%s", array[i]);
    }
} 

int main()
{
    char* messages[3];
    givetag(messages); //sub function 

    int i;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++) { 
        printf(messages[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

as you see in picture of out put, you must add malloc size (i change code).

[image: 1]